# javascript amCharts graph item click event

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, amcharts

In [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) flash chart there is a event name clickGraphItem which work as click on graph item and after fetching this event we can do any action on graph item click.

I need the same functionality in [javascript amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/). So is it possible to implement clickGraphItem in javascript amCharts?

Please provide solution. Any source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add event handlers to the AMCharts Javascript library in the following way

```
// add click listener
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", handleClick);
```

Here is jsFiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts2/cV8GG/

Comment: Good answer, does exactly what the OP asked.  I've added the key part of your jsFiddle example to your answer to save people needing to click through to get the line.