# How to handle click event on AmCharts Stock graph?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to do it using amStockCharts v3. 
I've seen this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668482/javascript-amcharts-graph-item-click-event), but it doesn't seems to work with Stock charts.

How can I handle click event for this chart - http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/?
I need to be able to get date and value corresponding to a clicked point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart) the stockchart itself does **not** support click events on the graph or items.
However, you can solve this by adding listeners to single panels. (see [docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#clickGraphItem))
As the panels are initialized after the chart `chart.panels[x].addListener()` won't work.
Instead you have to wrap it in the charts init event like this:

```
chart.addListener("init", function () {
    for( var x in chart.panels ) {
        chart.panels[x].addListener("clickGraphItem", function(e) {
            alert("index: "
                    + e.item.index
                    + "\nvalue: "
                    + e.item.values["value"]); //valuefield depends on your mapping!!!
        });
    }
});
```

Important for "clickGraphItem" is, that there must be an actual item to be clicked on. In other words there must be a bullet. If you don't want them to be seen, just set their alpha to zero.

```
bullet: "round",
bulletAlpha: 0
```

You can play around with the shape and size of the bullets, to change the click area.
I prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jjeukvz/) for you.