# How to attach click event on amCharts V3 - Pie chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How to add addListener on amCharts on pie chart? I am trying to use:

```
 function handleClick(event)
    {
        alert(event.item.category + ": " + event.item.values.value);
    }
 chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", handleClick);
```

But it is not working on Pie chart.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhbha/cy89ny3k/

Here is another answer on the same problem, but it is not working on version-3 charts: 
[javascript amCharts graph item click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668482/javascript-amcharts-graph-item-click-event)

Answer (score 2):

just add this:

```
chart.addListener("clickSlice", handleClick);
```

and

```
function handleClick(event)
        {
            alert();
        }
```

because the `event.item.category` is unknown

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cy89ny3k/2/